# How to send Notifications via Service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send the notification via service. The time of the notification is set from the database table where I have date, time etc columns. So when System.currentTimeMillis is equal to the time from database column I am trying to send the notification to the user. However my implementation doesn't work, could someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Here is my Service file

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("myLOgs", "Service: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("myLOgs", "Service: onStartCommand()");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(date);

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm");
        Date time = new Date();
        String currentTimeString = timeFormat.format(time);

        String[] columns = {DBHelper.DATE, DBHelper.TIME, DBHelper.EVENT};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String dateString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE));
            String timeString  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.TIME));
            String eventString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.EVENT));
            if((currentDateString.equals(dateString)) && (currentTimeString.equals(timeString))) {
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, eventString, System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            if(cursor.moveToLast()) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
        }while(true);

        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling notify()?

Comment: Oh, I forgot it, but even though after placing notify(), it doesn't work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use this method for giving notification from service.

Just make this method as member of your service class and then you can call this method from service class onStartCommand or wherever you needed.

Fully working i used in my project...

```
  private int notificationID = 100;

  private void giveNotification(String notificationTitle, String bodytext)
  {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DeliveryReport.class);

    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationID, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, bodytext, pendingIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID++, notification);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send notification you need to use **pending intent**

sample code for notification

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Intent notification = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notification.putExtra("message", message);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notification, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("sample").setContentText(message)

            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),
            mBuilder.getNotification());

    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, soundUri);

    r.play();
```